# calculate the derivative of $x + 1/x$ using the definition?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Calculate the derivative of $x + 1/x$ directly from the definition of the derivative 
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
$$

I think this is the first step: $((x+h) + 1/(x+h) -(x+1/x) )/h$? but I'm not sure what to do next. (The algebra seems pretty difficult.) Anyone know how to go about this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Simplify simplify simplify! Here is an example: $(x+h) + \frac{1}{x+h} = \frac{(x+h)^2 + 1}{x+h}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have to compute:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}.$$

In your situation, this is:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x + h) + 1/(x + h) - x - 1/x}{h} =$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h + 1/(x + h) - 1/x}{h} =$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{hx(h + x) + x - h - x}{x(x + h)}}{h} =$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{xh(x + h) - h}{xh(x + h)} =$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{x(x + h) - 1}{x(x + h)} =$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} 1 - \frac{1}{x(x + h)} =$$
$$1 - \frac{1}{x^2}.$$

Hence, $(x + \frac{1}{x})' = 1 - \frac{1}{x^2}.$

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=x+1/x$. Then

$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=
\frac{x+h+1/(x+h)-x-1/x}{h}=
\frac{hx(x+h)+x-x-h}{hx(x+h)}=
1-\frac{1}{x(x+h)}.
$$

The limit should now be easy to calculate.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{d}{dx}\Big(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\Big)=\dfrac{d}{dx}x+\dfrac{d}{dx}\underbrace{\dfrac{1}{x}}_{x^{-1}}$

Now use the limit definition.

$\dfrac{d}{dx}x=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{x+h-x}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{h}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}1=\boxed{1}$.
$\dfrac{d}{dx}x^{-1}=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{(x+h)^{-1}-x^{-1}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{x+h}-\dfrac{1}{x}}{h}=\lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{x-x-h}{hx^2-h^2x}=\lim_{h\to0} \dfrac{-1}{x^2-hx}=\boxed{-\dfrac{1}{x^2}}$

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\Big(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\Big)=1-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$$